# why reactive programming replacing observer pattern

Tags: java, c#, reactive-programming, observer-pattern

Reactive programming uses the idea of Observer Pattern . I am not looking for reasons why i have to use Reactive approach instead of observer pattern.I am seeing a lot of similarities between observer pattern and Reactive approach.
So why I will use Reactive programming deprecating observer pattern?

Answer (score 2):

There are probably many reasons, but my first take would be: *Reactive programming* is **much** more than just using the Observer pattern.

See the *reactive [manifesto](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/)* for example. That makes it clear that *reactive programming* has at least 4 important corners - responsiveness, resilience, elasticity, and "message-busing". Those are fundamental qualities; and none of them (directly) leads to "Observer pattern".

In essence, *reactive programming* is establishing a whole new set of practices/[patterns](https://www.manning.com/books/reactive-design-patterns); so reducing it to "replacing Observer patterns" as you put it ... is simply wrong.

In over words: I think your assessment is an over-simplification which is ignoring **major** parts of what makes up *reactive programming*.

Of course, when you are already using the observer pattern all over the place to solve your place, you are already living in the "reactive world" to a certain degree.

Comment: As observers are loosely coupled, it can be used to achieve elasticity and resilience. As the theory goes, subjects state can be saved and it can be good to use handling event according to that state. I need some use cases where i must have to use reactive instead of traditional approach?

Comment: What makes you think you *must* use a new technology? You study its concepts; and you figure what makes sense in your context; and that you use. Again: *reactive programming* is a whole new "architecture" style; not only a single pattern.